# How to compile multiple .py files into one exe?

Tags: python, file, compilation, exe

I've built a simple project containing 4 .py files in total. It works using pycharm but fails when I try to run it as an exe. In the main file, I use subprocess.Popen to open these files and sys.exit() to exit out of the main script. This is what is in the main.py file:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

def none_contr_run():
    Popen(["python", "none_contr.py"])
    sys.exit()


def div_rein_run():
    Popen(["python", "div_rein.py"])
    sys.exit()


def stable_annual_run():
    Popen(["python", "stable_annual.py"])
    sys.exit()
```

and in each of the files there is a return function like this:

```
def return_main():
    Popen(['python','main.py'])
    sys.exit()
```

When I try to run this program as an exe, what is inside of main.py works fine, but the script closes itself as soon as I call one of the functions above. What could be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you have created .exe file using Pyinstaller it will be stored in dist path. The only thing you have to do is move it into your main files and the problem will be resolved.
It was due to the path difference.

Comment: I have moved it into the folder where all of the files are stored and it still doesn't work. I used 'pyinstaller --onefile main.py' command, maybe I should use a diffrent command?